# Iterate through int array of unknown length

Tags: c, microcontroller

I am trying to iterate through an array that will contain **up to** a maximum of 4 elements - no other knowledge of the array-length exists.

**Pseudo Code**

```
void insert_vals(uint8_t num, uint8_t *match_num, uint8_t *value)
{
    uint8_t i;

    while(data_exists)  // how do I determine if data exists in 'value'?
    {
        switch(num)
        {
            case 0:
            {
                switch(match_num[i])
                {
                    case 0:
                        hw0reg0 = value[i];
                    case 1:
                        hw0reg1 = value[i];
                    case 2:
                        hw0reg2 = value[i];
                    case 3:
                        hw0reg3 = value[i];
                }
            }
            case 1:
            {
                switch(match_num[i])
                {
                    case 0:
                        hw1reg0 = value[i];
                    case 1:
                        hw1reg1 = value[i];
                    case 2:
                        hw1reg2 = value[i];
                    case 3:
                        hw1reg3 = value[i];                 
                }
            }
            // etc. 2 other cases
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Calling Example (Pseudo Code)**

```
/*
 * num: hardware device select from 1 - 4
 * match_num: 4 possible matches for each hardware device
 * value: 32-bit values to be assigned to 4 possible matches
 * NOTE: This function assumes hardware devices are selected
 * in a consecutive order; I will change this later.
 */

 // example calling code - we could have configured 4 hardware devices
 insert_vals(0, [0, 1], [0x00000001, 0x000000FF]);  // arg2 and arg3 equal in length
```

How can I accomplish this?

In a character array, C will automatically add `'\0'` to the end of the array, but this does not seem to be the case for an integer array. If I  was somehow able to determine the length of `match_num` and `value` (see `if` statement) at runtime originally, then that would allow me to create a `for` loop.

## Edit

Since I know that there will be a maximum of 4 elements, couldn't I do something similar to the following?

```
void insert_vals(uint8_t num, uint8_t *match_num, uint32_t *value)
{
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(value[i] == -1)
            break;
        else
        {
            // Assign data
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the calling code.

Comment: Sorry guys - there you go.

Comment: @Biff This calling code compiles for you?

Comment: No, this is merely pseudo code. I probably would have to declare the array *outside* of the function call, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your intention. I don't understand your pseudocode either. Could you please elaborate? BTW: what is `data_exists` ?

Comment: @Biff, for the register assignments, I'd recommend using macros and ##.  BTW, macros are not evil in C.

Comment: @JoshPetitt, Thanks for the tip - I'm learning as I go, so this is great.

Comment: Checkout the edit guys - all I am looking for is a way to assign data to specific registers, and since I will have an `init` function that will use this function, this will be in compile-time.

Comment: @Biff, good luck on your journey.  If you are learning, then macros with ## may not actually be a good suggestion for you to implement.  If you really are doing embedded, then I'd recommend you look through your compiler vendors code for manipulating registers and do it like that.  (they probably have some helper functions/macros for setting up some of the peripherals)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get the length of an array pointed to given only the pointer. Either you have to pass the length, or it must be constant (always 4) with some sentinel value in the unused elements -- a value that is somehow invalid for your computations (like NUL is for strings).

Comment: Assuming I did pass in the length, would that mean `sizeof(my_array)/sizeof(int)` would work at compile-time *if outside the function* like you say?

Comment: @Biff: that would work of the division is performed at some place where `my_array` is actually an array (not a pointer).

Comment: That would mean changing my arguments as `match_num[]` and `value[]`, respectively. Correct?

Comment: @Biff: no, that wouldn't change a thing as it's just syntactic sugar for pointer arguments.

Comment: How do I distinguish between the two? Is there material I can read?

Comment: @Biff: You can't pass arrays to functions or return them from functions, simple as that.  This isn't exactly a new problem; you need to pass the length along with the pointer (or add an end marker).

Comment: @Biff, pass the length.  This is the C way.  Look at memset, memcmp, or memcpy for similar examples of this pattern.

Comment: @Biff, the biggest question is "do I pass the number of bytes, or the number of elements?"  If you have an array of elements you are processing, I recommend using unsigned as the type for the number of elements, if you are processing bytes, then use size_t at the type for the number of bytes to process.  A lot of C "rules" are merely policy and convention by programmers rather than enforcement by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a value you can guarantee it's not in the "usable" data? (e.g. 0 is no valid character for character strings, therefore Mr. Kernighan and Mr. Ritchie decided to pick it as a "end of array" marker. You could do the same with any value.

Say you know your integer values are between 0 to 512, so you could initialize the whole array e.g. to 1024, then fill it and iterate through it until a number >512 occurs (which has to be your end of array marker).

Another possibility is to pass the number of elements in the array along with the array.